# foliations subdivided into maximally distinct classes that preserve some global metric?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, curves, motivation, foliations

It's simple to construct an analytic codimension one foliation of $\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}$ with one class of functions. I wonder if there are pros and or cons of using more distinct classes of functions for the foliation.

For example is it possible to have a codimension one foliation of $\Bbb R^2_{\gt 0}$ with distinct analytic classes of functions $f_t(x)\ne g_t(x)\ne h_t(x)$ where $t$ indexes the leaves?

I have found an example of such. However, I still would like to know:

> Is there any motivation for building the foliation by maximizing the distinct classes of functions as opposed to constructing a foliation using only one class of functions?

Just thinking about some possible motivations for this, I thought that using one class of functions for the foliation might make for a vector field tangent to the leaves easier to write down and describe. And that's definitely useful.

However, I think introducing variation in the leaves of the foliation could create richer dynamics with the vector field that is tangent to the leaves.

> A question that comes to my mind is: Do the collection of some given distinct classes of leaves preserve some global metric?

An example for one class of functions I can provide is $(M,g,\mathcal F)$ with metric tensor $g=dudv$ and foliation comprised of a single class of functions, $\mathcal F=\lbrace t/x:t\in \Bbb R_{\gt 0} \rbrace.$ It can be shown that the infintesimally generated flow tangent to $\mathcal F$ preserves $g$.

However at this moment it's unclear to me how to stitch together mutually distinct one parameter classes of functions that preserve some global metric.

Comment: What is a "class of functions"? How do you distinguish different ones?

Comment: A class of functions is a family of functions (they change according to some parameter). I distinguish different classes by their form, for example $\mathcal F=\lbrace t/x:t\in \Bbb R_{\gt 0} \rbrace$ would be different than $G=\lbrace tx: t \in \Bbb R_{\gt 0}\rbrace. $

Comment: This is still too vague. Presumably your functions have some kind of restricted domain and range. Presumably there are some classes of functions which are related, in some fashion, to foliations... but... presumably not *all* classes of functions are related to foliations. But none of this is defined. It's not possible to craft an answer to your question without having *some* precise mathematical definitions to go on.